# unterminated character when parsing json in android

Tags: android, android-activity, retrofit, android-json

I am using the Retrofit package from square to make http request to my server. I get json data from my server that needs to be parsed. The problem I'm having is when the name field has more than one word I get a "Unterminated object at character". What can be the problem.

This works fine
{results=[{id=23.0, name= Canada}]}

This does not

{results=[{id=23.0, name= United States}]}

```
JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(data);

             JSONArray result = jsonResponse.getJSONArray("results");

            for(int i=0; i <result.length();i++ )
            {
                 MyObj obj = new MyObj();
                obj.id= result.getJSONObject(i).optString("id").toString();
                obj.name=result.getJSONObject(i).optString("name").toString();

                p.add(obj);
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your input is not valid according to the JSON specs.

It shoud be:

```
{"results":[{"id":23.0, "name":"United States"}]}
```

See: http://json.org/

Comment: @sararoberts I don't know, a JSON parser is expected to behave well when parsing valid JSON. When parsing an invalid JSON input, its behavior is not predictable and should not pay attention to its results.